# How can I have text move to a new line without an indent or without the use of <br>

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-alignment

I am working on this section and I am trying not to use line breaks for the text but for some reason when my text moves to a new line it is spaced. I want it to be equal without any indent. The text should stay within the defined width.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFCXi.png)

This is what I have so far. I have tried a few methods to adjust the CSS, but none of them worked. Please feel free to play around with the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      .card-section {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .card {
        flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .card img {
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 1em;
      }

      .card-title {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .card-description {
        
  width: 90%;
      padding-bottom: 1.4rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
}

      .apply-today {
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      a:visited{
  color: #000;;
}

      .apply-today:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* For tablets */
        .card {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        /* For mobile phones */
        .card {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .card img {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .card-title {
          font-size: 20px;
        }

        .card-description {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="card-section">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/db15gy9h6/image/upload/v1678186694/Screenshot_from_2023-03-07_13-56-08_i5cvoh.png" alt="Card Image 1">
        <h2 class="card-title">Title 1</h2>
        <p class="card-description"> Elewa talents taking the next steps in their careers , fully funded by
        Elewa Group (equity investments).</p>
        <p class="apply-today"><u>APPLY TODAY</u></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/db15gy9h6/image/upload/v1678186694/Screenshot_from_2023-03-07_13-56-48_xiwl9o.png" alt="Card Image 2">
        <h2 class="card-title">Title 2</h2>
        <p class="card-description">External startups incubated by the Elewa Creative Hub (Tenants, partnerships & small-scale investments)</p>
        <p class="apply-today"><a href="">APPLY TODAY</a></p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  Please read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  Then comeback and [edit] the question to make it easier to understand your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the `h1` and everything else to be centered, add `text-align: left` to  the rule for `.card-description`:

Edit/addition after comment: Also, limit the `width` of `.card-description` to the same amount as for the image (i.e. 50%) and center it by adding `margin: 0 auto;`

(BTW: Whether you leave the `text-align: center` in the rule for `.card`, depends on whether you want the `h1` heading and the "apply"-button centered or left-aligned. If you want them left-aligned, you can erase that setting, but then you should also add `width: 50%` to their CSS rules.)

```css
.card-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.card-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-description {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.apply-today {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: #000;
  ;
}

.apply-today:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For tablets */
  .card {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* For mobile phones */
  .card {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .card img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card-title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .card-description {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="card-section">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/db15gy9h6/image/upload/v1678186694/Screenshot_from_2023-03-07_13-56-08_i5cvoh.png" alt="Card Image 1">
    <h2 class="card-title">Title 1</h2>
    <p class="card-description"> Elewa talents taking the next steps in their careers , fully funded by Elewa Group (equity investments).</p>
    <p class="apply-today"><u>APPLY TODAY</u></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/db15gy9h6/image/upload/v1678186694/Screenshot_from_2023-03-07_13-56-48_xiwl9o.png" alt="Card Image 2">
    <h2 class="card-title">Title 2</h2>
    <p class="card-description">External startups incubated by the Elewa Creative Hub (Tenants, partnerships & small-scale investments)</p>
    <p class="apply-today"><a href="">APPLY TODAY</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice, I tried that, but I want the text to be in the center like in the design image. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29625264/223031801-8811f8d2-cf29-417b-97e9-fa5ac2cdcd34.png

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer and snippet.

Comment: If you take a closer look, `text-align: center;` is not needed. Just nitpicking. :)